# How to fix autosuggest for Pyspark in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyspark

VS Code version: 1.81.1
Python version 3.8.10
Pyspark 3.4.1
venv set up, and activated. Pyspark pip-installed in venv.

Auto suggest not working properly.

Can ctrl + click SparkSession, builder, SparkConf to go to code

Can not ctrl + click enableHiveSupport, config, getOrCreate, read, parquet

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame
from pyspark import SparkConf

spark = (
        SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport()
        .config(conf=SparkConf())
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
        .config(
            "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
        )
        .getOrCreate()
    )

source_df = spark.read.parquet(
    "path"
)

SparkSession. #Suggestions appear
spark. #no suggestions
DataFrame. #Suggestions appear
source_df. #no suggestions
```